# ArcMap - Labeling Expression - If-then, else

Tags: arcmap, labeling, expression, if-statement

I am very new to writing expressions. I am working with address data. We want to display the street number and #unit number if there is a unit, and just the street number if the unit field is empty. I have mimicked various scripts (VBScript & Python) provided in other helpful posts, but I am still getting the # after the street number if the unit field is empty. I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly. [image: Screenshot of label expression and label display]
The script I used:

```
Function FindLabel ( [STNUM] , [UNIT] )
if [UNIT] <> " " Then
  FindLabel = [STNUM] + " " +  "#" + [UNIT]
else
 FindLabel = [STNUM] 
end if
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the `if [UNIT] <> " "` that cause problem. By testing for `" "` you are looking for a space you should try with `""` (empty string) or  `IS NULL` depending on your field type (text or numeric, if it's a text field you may want to check that the "empty" cells are consistant).

Comment: Yes! That appeared to fix it. Thank you!